# local persistant volume & nodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes

I am using **local** persistant volumes in my Kubernetes cluster, I have currently two worker nodes in my cluster(node1, node2). So while creating local Peristant Volume I have added node affinity with these nodes.

```
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
          - node2
```

10 deployments are working using these PVs. Now, I want to add a new worker node to the cluster(node3). I tried to modify the Persistent Volume but I can't modify the nodeAffinity as this is showing **"field is immutable"**. How should I proceed now? If I don't modify the PV, pods will not get scheduled on the new worker node?

How to tackle this situation?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your PV capacity, your persistent volume claim and what version of kubernetes you are using?

Comment: Using v1.17, using Local PV with 50Gi, Using it for logs persistance only. Not for any Datasource like DB or something else

Answer (score 1):

When a field is immutable, what you could do is delete the parent object, with the option `cascade` option set to orphan (used to be "false" in older versions / if "orphan" isn't recognized)

See [kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/use-cascading-deletion/#set-orphan-deletion-policy).

Having your new configuration ready, delete the old object

```
kubectl delete deploy/example --cascade=orphan
```

Its child replicaset and pods should still exist. At which point, you can create the replacement deployment.